# PHP jqgrid: prevent collapse of groups

Tags: php, jqgrid, grouping

I have a jqGrid with data grouped by cities and then by companies. I would like to prevent the parent nodes (cities) from collapsing and take the collapse/expand (symbol +/-) out of the grid.

Do you know how to do it?

PS I am using the commercial version of the grid.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using subgrids?

Each of the `+` / `-` cells is encapsulated in a `<td>` element with the `ui-sgcollapsed` class, eg:

```
<td role="gridcell" 
    aria-describedby="list11_subgrid" 
    class="ui-sgcollapsed sgexpanded" 
    style="">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

You can use a selector such as `jQuery('.ui-sgcollapsed')` to find these elements and [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) any [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) events, to prevent a user from collapsing any rows.

Of course, before you do this, you will need to expand each row so the subgrid is displayed. The easiest way to do this is probably to use the [`expandOnLoad: true`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid) option.

Does that help?

---

On the other hand, are you sure this is what you want? Is it good enough to just expand everything by default, and give your users the choice to collapse rows if necessary, to view more at a time or whatever the user needs?